# CRM 2016 RetrieveMultiple Plugin to filter emails

Tags: c#, linq, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a requirement to mark certain emails as confidential. These emails should not be visible in the CRM system unless you have a specific role. I created a 'Confidential' flag on the email entity and Created a plugin on the RetrieveMultiple of email entity, which filters out all emails which has 'Confidential' = true.

However, the email records are still visible under 'Activities'. I created another plugin on retrievemultiple of the activitypointer entity but I am unable to create a query that will show all activities (including emails) except emails marked as 'Confidential'. Can anyone help me with the linq query for this ? This is what I have created

```
QueryExpression objQueryExpression1 = (QueryExpression)context.InputParameters["Query"];

objQueryExpression1.LinkEntities.Add(new LinkEntity("activitypointer", "email", "activityid", "activityid", JoinOperator.LeftOuter));

objQueryExpression1.LinkEntities[0].EntityAlias = "filteredemails";
objQueryExpression1.LinkEntities[0].LinkCriteria.AddCondition("csiro_confidential", ConditionOperator.Equal, true);
```

Comment: I guess, It should be ConditionOperator.NotEqual and JoinOperator.Inner

Comment: you can query email entity, and that should only bring the emails having Confidential = true 
Can you share the query you wrote for email entity ?

Comment: @ArunVinoth - Doesn't work. It filters out the confidential emails all right, but it also filters out all the other activity types (as the join is an inner join)

Comment: @mzh - The plugin on the email entity works fine. If I try to query only the email entity I do not see the confidential emails. However, the plugin on the activitypointer entity doesn't filter the emails. the activitypointer entity also has links to the emails, and the confidential emails are seen in the 'Activities' folder.

Comment: Then NotEqual + LeftOuter should work for you, right?

Comment: @ArunVinoth Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. It still shows the Confidential emails.

Comment: Refer this thread: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/187457

Comment: Sounds like this may not be achievable. https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c0341f8c-3fbc-42a3-bc74-fa4d83ac0a79/how-to-retrieve-activity-based-on-activitypointer-using-fetchxml-in-dynamics-crm-2011?forum=crmdevelopment

Comment: Try this last hope & let us know: https://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/nathan-eccless-blog/2013/01/25/crm-2011-activitypointer-and-custom-fields

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to change the owner of the e-mail to a Team if it's supposed to be confidential, and restrict access via normal security?

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can do as following,

```
QueryExpression objQueryExpression1 = (QueryExpression)context.InputParameters["Query"];

                if (objQueryExpression1.EntityName == "email")
                {
                    objQueryExpression1.Criteria = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And)
                    {
                        Conditions =
                        {
                            new ConditionExpression("new_confidential",ConditionOperator.NotEqual,true)
                        }
                    };
                }
                else if (objQueryExpression1.EntityName == "activitypointer")
                {
                    QueryExpression e = new QueryExpression("email")
                    {
                        Criteria = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And)
                        {
                            Conditions =
                            {
                                new ConditionExpression("csiro_confidential",ConditionOperator.NotEqual,true)
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    var filteredOutEmails = service.RetrieveMultiple(e).Entities.Select(xc => xc.Id.ToString()).ToArray();

                    objQueryExpression1.Criteria.AddCondition("activityid", ConditionOperator.NotIn,filteredOutEmails);

                }
                context.InputParameters["Query"] = objQueryExpression1;
```

> Register Your plugin for both **email** and **activitypointer** entities, on
>   Pre-operation with Synchronous mode

screenshot attached [image]

Comment: @mzh- Unfortunately this still doesn't work as intended. While the plugin works fine on the activity entity, it does the opposite of the intended behaviour on the email entity. i.e. it shows all confidential emails, and filters out everything else.

Comment: He might have put wrong filters/conditions.. change it to right filter/conditions per your need & test it..

Comment: @Manish you should change the filter according to your need, it is just how you need to do it. Don't just copy and paste, change the conditions as per you need it ;-)

Comment: @mzh - The issue is with the logic. The requirement is to filter out all emails where confidential = true. This filter needs to apply on both email entity and activity entity. Going by your code above, and registering the plugin  for both email & activity entities causes the following issue. 1. The code section for email filters out all confidential emails and shows only non-confidential emails (after changing the filter)

Comment: However, when the code executes for activities, it has a retrievemultiple call within itself to the email entity (filteredoutemails), which returns non-confidential emails. Add your criteria of filtering out filteredoutemails from the activity entity, it will end up showing confidential emails on the activity entity.

Comment: @mzh thus the code does one of the following
1. It either hides confidential emails from the email entity, but shows them on the activity entity OR
2. If you change the filters on the email query, it will show the confidential emails on the email entity and hide them from the activity entity.

Comment: @Manish code is updated. try it now. You should paste your code here as well so that we can understand, how you are adding the filters to query expression.

Comment: The point is RetreiveMultiple for filteredout will trigger this plugin again & execute the first part :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known behavior](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c0341f8c-3fbc-42a3-bc74-fa4d83ac0a79/how-to-retrieve-activity-based-on-activitypointer-using-fetchxml-in-dynamics-crm-2011?forum=crmdevelopment) with ActivityPointer, as the custom attribute (filter) you created is dedicated for one type of activity. ie Email in your case.

In Email views or Email only related queries, this works well. Other activities are not aware of this custom attribute & ActivityPointer as well.

You have to do OUTERJOIN for [individual activity](https://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/nathan-eccless-blog/2013/01/25/crm-2011-activitypointer-and-custom-fields) types (what are all you are using in your system?) & compose the query.

Try something like this:

```
QueryExpression objQueryExpression1 = (QueryExpression)context.InputParameters["Query"];

objQueryExpression1.LinkEntities.Add(new LinkEntity("activitypointer", "email", "activityid", "activityid", JoinOperator.LeftOuter));

objQueryExpression1.LinkEntities[0].EntityAlias = "filteredemails";
objQueryExpression1.LinkEntities[0].LinkCriteria.AddCondition("csiro_confidential", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, true);

objQueryExpression1.LinkEntities.Add(new LinkEntity("activitypointer", "task", "activityid", "activityid", JoinOperator.LeftOuter));

objQueryExpression1.LinkEntities[1].EntityAlias = "filteredTasks";
objQueryExpression1.LinkEntities[1].LinkCriteria.AddCondition("csiro_newfield", ConditionOperator.Equal, true);
```

Comment: I tried the OUTERJOIN on all activity types, but it still didn't work. However, I found a workaround - I updated the duration of the email to a large number (999 days), and then updated the plugin on the activitypointer to filter out records where duration = 999 days. It works now on the advanced find and the 'Regarding' record.

However, I've now discovered a new problem. The activities still show up on the contact's (Email : To) Social Pane as well as on the related activities for the contact. Any idea why ?

Comment: Like Daryl suggested, can you try role based or object based security concepts rather than this roundabout..?

Comment: But why does it work in Advanced Find and activitypane of the Regarding Entity but show up in the activitypane of the Contact entity ?

Comment: Broad in SO. Post a separate question.